# which version of angular and ionic should i choose

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, e-commerce

I want to create an e-commerce website with angular and the mobile application with ionic which version should I choose as a beginner, my project should be ready in two months

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an ecommerce site in Angular and Ionic - then I would suggest that you use [ngx-rocket](https://github.com/ngx-rocket) to scaffold your project.

It will set up an angular project for you, in a state of the art setup - and durring generation Ionic is an option for the generated code. It will set you up with Angular 7+ and also latest stable version of Ionic.

It only takes 10 minutes to get started with, so I suggest you take a look at it in order to possibly save some time.

Comment: Learn to recognize off topic posts, then don't answer them.

Answer (score -1):

Use Ionic 4 and Angular 7. Ionic 4 uses routing which makes it easier for your to learn both Angular and ionic at the same time